# Returning a cursor from a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return a cursor from a procedure which will display the contents of a table `invoice`.  The package and procedure was successfully created but when I run the line - `Exec CursorPckg.CursorTest_Proc();` I get the following error `component 'CURSORTEST_PROC' must be declared` any ideas? I'm running SQL*PLUS

```
CREATE or REPLACE PACKAGE CursorPckg
IS
  TYPE salary_type IS REF CURSOR RETURN Invoice%ROWTYPE;
END CursorPckg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CursorPckg AS
  PROCEDURE CursorTest_Proc (c1 OUT CursorPckg.salary_type) 
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN c1 FOR 
    SELECT * FROM Invoice;
  END CursorTest_Proc;
END CursorPckg;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add procedure declaration in package declaration for it to be accessible from outside your package.
Like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PACKAGE CursorPckg
IS
TYPE salary_type IS REF CURSOR RETURN Invoice%ROWTYPE;
PROCEDURE CursorTest_Proc (c1 OUT CursorPckg.salary_type);
END CursorPckg;
```

**Edit:**

To answer Your comment. You cannot execute this procedure without providing parameter of type `CursorPckg.salary_type`.

Comment: how to i execute the procedure , i tried this line but it does not work:

Comment: Exec CursorPckg.CursorTest_Proc();

Comment: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CURSORTEST_PROC'